# Draw rectangular seek bar

Tags: android

At initial stage image will be shown like this.
[image]

When i touch border part of image and moving clockwise direction on border of image then region should be covered with blue color same as below image. Please give any idea to draw a pattern like this. Any suggestion would be appreiciable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply show a progressbar around an image. And this progressbar can be configured in a lot of different ways, like colour, outline, display of the percentage and so on.

Eg :https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar/wiki/Usage

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1340

Answer (score 0):

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar_volume"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="100"
android:progress="0"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal"
android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control_selector_holo_light"/>
```

and create two custo drawable 
scrubber_progress_horizontal.xml

```
<layer-list>
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/urseekbarimage.png"/>
    <item android:id="android:id/secondaryProgress>
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" android:drawable="@drawable/urseekbar2.png"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" android:drawable/urseekbar3.png"/>
    </item>
</laye-list>
```

and another xml file named as scrubber_control_selector_holo_right.xml
and put code like this

```
<selector>
<item android:state_enabled="false"android="@drawable/yourthumbicon"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true"android="@drawable/yourthumbicon2"/>
<itemandroid:state_selected="true"android="@drawable/yourthumbicon3"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/yournormalthumbicon"/>
</selector>
```

if it helps you please let me know